# listview item open activity

Tags: android, listview, onclick

I have an error when i click on item in activity they all show me the same string which his name: "name_0"

the activity which is open when we click:

```
public void handle() {
    TextView var3 = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.name);
    TextView var2 = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.meaning);
    TextView var5 = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.proof);
    Intent var4 = this.getIntent();
    int var1 = var4.getIntExtra("name", 0);
    switch (var1) {
    case 0:
        var3.setText(R.string.name_0);
        var2.setText(R.string.meaning_0);
        var5.setText(R.string.proof_0);
        break;
    case 1:
        var3.setText(R.string.name_1);
        var2.setText(R.string.meaning_1);
        var5.setText(R.string.proof_1);
        break;
    case 2:
        var3.setText(R.string.name_2);
        var2.setText(R.string.meaning_2);
        var5.setText(R.string.proof_2);
        break;    

            }
}
```

and the activity who open the item onclick:

```
String[] values = { "test", "list", "ok", "bon" };

protected void onCreate(Bundle var1) {
    super.onCreate(var1);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    this.listView = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.list);
    listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.listview_item,
            R.id.textView_list, values));
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long arg) {
              Intent Start = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Asma2Ma3anihaActivity.class);
               startActivity(Start);
           } 
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are not sending the position of the clicked item

```
Intent start = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Asma2Ma3anihaActivity.class);
start.putExtra("name", position);
startActivity(start);
```

That should work.

You always got 0 because you set 0 here (`var4.getIntExtra("name", 0);`) as the default value when the "name" key is missing.

Answer (score 0):

You never set the 'name' extra on your Intent when you create it in the setOnItemClickListener, so when you try and retrieve the int in the 'handle()' method, you will always get 0.

You have to set the extra on the intent before you do 'startActivity'.

```
Intent startIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Asma2Ma3anihaActivity.class);
startIntent.putExtra("name", position);
startActivity(startIntent);
```

Comment: Thank's to you also :D

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the text from the item you need to get the value from the view you get from the itemclicklistener

i.e

```
     listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long arg) {
              String text = ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText();
              Intent Start = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Asma2Ma3anihaActivity.class).putExtra("name",text);
              startActivity(Start);
       } 
    });
```